# Not resizable JFrame changes location on pack()

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, resize, jframe

I want to write a `JFrame` which has content of changing size. The `JFrame` should adjust to the size of its content. Additionally, the `JFrame` should not be resizable.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyFrame();
    }

    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel label;
    private boolean labelVisible = false;

    public MyFrame() {
        label = new JLabel("label");

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        frame.getContentPane().add(createButton());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JButton createButton() {
        JButton button = new JButton("toggleLabel");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (labelVisible) {
                    frame.getContentPane().remove(label);
                } else {
                    frame.getContentPane().add(label);
                }
                labelVisible = !labelVisible;
                frame.pack();
                System.out.println(frame.getLocation());
            }
        });
        return button;
    }
}
```

Here is the problem: If I resize the `JFrame` (by adding or removing a label), the `JFrame` changes its location (it moves down a bit). However, if I remove the line `frame.setResizable(false)`, the location of the `JFrame` will not be changed anymore.

Can I do anything about that? Can I have a `JFrame` that is not resizable by the user, but resizable by the code?

---

Edit:

Here is the output after clicking the button several times:

```
java.awt.Point[x=75,y=62]
java.awt.Point[x=75,y=90]
java.awt.Point[x=75,y=118]
java.awt.Point[x=75,y=146]
java.awt.Point[x=75,y=174]
java.awt.Point[x=75,y=202]
java.awt.Point[x=75,y=230]
java.awt.Point[x=75,y=286]
java.awt.Point[x=75,y=286]
java.awt.Point[x=75,y=314]
java.awt.Point[x=75,y=342]
```

As you can see, the y-coordinate increases with every click.

---

Edit2:

As @camickr pointed out in the comments, it seems to be a platform specific problem.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit with java-7-oracle 64-bit (1.7.0_67).

Comment: I don't see this problem. The frame just increases in height as I click on the button. I also added `System.out.println(frame.getLocation());` after the `frame.pack()` and the location never changes. I'm using JDK7_19 on Windows 7. Maybe this is a version/platform issue?

Comment: I was expecting you to provide your JDK version and OS so other people using the same environment as you can check if the code works or not.

Comment: @usar, that information doesn't help unless we know the version/platform. Only then can we determine if there is a pattern or perhaps a bug on a specific version/platform.

Comment: @camickr Thanks for trying it out. I changed the question, so it contains the `System.out.println` output and my platform informations.

Comment: @usar I tried GridLayout, BoxLayout and BorderLayout. It does not change the behaviour.

Comment: I noticed that your y-location changes exactly by 28 which is the height of the window bar at the top (on my Mac). In my case, the location _decreases_ by 27 on packing even if I don't do anything with the frame! I am asking a separate question and will include the link to that here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71809915/why-does-jframe-pack-affect-the-location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using exactly the same code and the output is this:

```
java.awt.Point[x=894,y=493]
java.awt.Point[x=894,y=493]
java.awt.Point[x=894,y=493]
java.awt.Point[x=894,y=493]
java.awt.Point[x=894,y=493]
java.awt.Point[x=894,y=493]
java.awt.Point[x=894,y=493]
java.awt.Point[x=894,y=493]
java.awt.Point[x=894,y=493]
```

It could be a platform related problem...

Answer (score 2):

As I already stated I don't have a problem. I don't see a problem with the basic code. Maybe it is a version/platform bug?

As a work around you should be able to do something like:

```
Point location = frame.getLocation();
frame.pack();
frame.setLocation( location );
```

Comment: Just tried it out, it does not work. The behaviour is the same as with the original code.

Comment: @primitivwurzel, did you verify the location is a value that you expect? You could try wrapping the `frame.setLocation()` in a SwingUtitlities.invokeLater(). This will add the code to the end of the EDT which should override the value being set by the pack() statement.

Comment: The value of the location seems to be reasonable. By using `SwingUtitlities.invokeLater()` the `JFrame` only moves down, when I add the label. The reset of the location works when I remove the label.

Comment: @primitivwurzel `The reset of the location works when I remove the label` some progress. The only other idea (hack) I have is to get the location of the frame before adding/removing the label. Something strange is going on. I would call this a bug.

Comment: I tried it out, but strangely enough this also does not work. I also think it is a bug. Thanks for your help!