# Why does JFrame pack() affect the location?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have looked at [Not resizable JFrame changes location on pack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475972/not-resizable-jframe-changes-location-on-pack) and one other. My situation is much simpler and different. The code is below:

```
public static void main_TestLoc()
{
    System.out.println("         Java Version: " + System.getProperty("java.version").toString());
    System.out.println("      Java VM Version: " + System.getProperty("java.vm.version").toString());
    System.out.println("Java  Runtime Version: " + System.getProperty("java.runtime.version").toString());
    System.out.println("          OS Platform: " + System.getProperty("os.name"));
    
    System.out.println();
    
    JFrame displayFrame = new JFrame();
    
    displayFrame.setLocation(200, 200);
    
    System.out.printf("Loc Before: (%4d, %4d)\n",
            displayFrame.getLocation().x,
            displayFrame.getLocation().y);
    
    displayFrame.pack();
    
    System.out.printf(" Loc After: (%4d, %4d)\n",
            displayFrame.getLocation().x,
            displayFrame.getLocation().y);

    displayFrame.setVisible(true);
    
    System.exit(0);
}
```

The output is below:

```
         Java Version: 17.0.2
      Java VM Version: 17.0.2+8
Java  Runtime Version: 17.0.2+8
          OS Platform: Mac OS X

Loc Before: ( 200,  200)
 Loc After: ( 200,  173)
```

The question is pack() is supposed to change the size of the Frame; why does it change the location? And how to stop it from doing so? Note: this behavior of pack() does not change when I place components in the frame.

Comment: @user16320675 In the referenced question a comment was made that the problem was platform dependent. I have therefore provided that information. Other than that, this is the minimal code that reproduces the problem in my system. Also, when I use setUndecorated(true), the location does not change  (i.e., the problem goes away). But I need the  decoration. Interestingly, the decoration size is 28 while the location moves up by 27.

Comment: I run Windows so presumably will not be able to see the problem directly. For my part, I wouldn't bother investigating in any case, instead opting for calling `setLocation` **after** `pack`. But then, I'd also use `setLocationByPlatform(true)` in lieu of `setLocation` and likely never notice the problem in the first place. 

Comment: Move the `setLocation` method call after the `pack` call.  The `pack` method is what sets the actual size of the `JFrame`.

Comment: @gilbert-le-blanc setting the location after pack() also works as a workaround.

Comment: @andrew-thompson I tried setLocationByPlatform(true) but does not seem to work.